# Android lint warns about 'TypedArray' used without 'try'-with-resources statement. how to resolve it?

Tags: android, lint

I have following code:

```
 public RVIndicator(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.RVIndicator, defStyleAttr, R.style.RVIndicator);
    dotColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.RVIndicator_dotColor, 0);
    selectedDotColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.RVIndicator_dotSelectedColor, dotColor);
    dotNormalSize = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RVIndicator_dotSize, 0);

    spaceBetweenDotCenters = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RVIndicator_dotSpacing, 0) + dotNormalSize;
    looped = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.RVIndicator_looped, false);
    int visibleDotCount = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.RVIndicator_visibleDotCount, 0);
    setVisibleDotCount(visibleDotCount);
    visibleDotThreshold = 0;
    attributes.recycle();

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    if (isInEditMode()) {
        setDotCount(visibleDotCount);
        onPageScrolled(visibleDotCount / 2, 0);
    }
}
```

for following statement lint gives warning 'TypedArray' used without 'try'-with-resources statement'. How to resolve this warning?

```
TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.RVIndicator, defStyleAttr, R.style.RVIndicator);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`TypedArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray#close()) implements [`AutoClosable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/AutoCloseable) which means you can use it in a try-with-resources like this:

```
try (TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.RVIndicator, defStyleAttr, R.style.RVIndicator)) {
    dotColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.RVIndicator_dotColor, 0);
    // rest of your code using attributes
    visibleDotThreshold = 0;
    // notably *no* call to attributes.recycle()
    // the try-with-resources makes sure that close() is called
}
```

This guarantees that the `TypedArray`is correctly recycled/closed even when some exception happens in that code block.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `TypedArray.close()` is actually calling `recycle()`. And also that try-with-resources is only available starting at API 31 (S).

Comment: So what do I need to do for API < 31 ?

Comment: @ProjectDelta just call recycle() when done with it I guess.